# How to create array DbParameter[]

Tags: c#, sql, executescalar

The manual says that the ExecuteScalar method should be used like:

```
public T ExecuteScalar<T>( 
   string commandText,
   CommandType commandType,
   params DbParameter[] parameters
)
```

But how do I create that array of parameters? I need to provide my stored procedure 2 parameters.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that manual? [DbCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar.aspx)  has no parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- DbParameter is an abstract class.
- Since the type T can not be inferred from the usage, you have to specify it.
- Althought you can just pass a variable number of parameters without creating the array, if you are dynamically creating a variable number of parameters, the array is your friend.

  ```
  var parameters = new[]{
              new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="foo", Value="hello" },
              new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="bar", Value="World" }
          };
  x.ExecuteScalar<int>(commandText, commandType, parameters);
  ```

Comment: both answers work fine, but i prefer this one a bit more that the other. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The `parameters` parameter has  the [`params` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). This means that you don't have to create the array explicitly but can pass a variable number of arguments to the method:

```
x.ExecuteScalar(commandText, commandType, parameter1, parameter2);
```

However, if you want, you can create the array explictly and pass it to the method as follows:

```
DbParameter[] parameters = new DbParameter[] { parameter1, parameter2 };

x.ExecuteScalar(commandText, commandType, parameters);
```

Answer (score 3):

DbParameter is an abstract class - but you can instantiate the derived type.

If you are using Sql server it is SqlParameter:

```
 DbParameter[] parameters = new DbParameter[2]; 
 parameters[0]  = new SqlParameter("param1",  123456);
 parameters[1]  = new SqlParameter("param2",  "abcdef");
```

Comment: That's an instant "index out of range" exception... should be `parameters[1]`

Answer (score 1):

The params keyword means that you can specify a varying number of parameters (so from 1 to [pretty much] infinity).

You can just call the method like this:
`ExecuteScalar<SomeType>("Command!", CommandType.SomeCommandType, dbParameter1, dbParameter2);`

Answer (score 0):

In a "perfect world" you should create any single parameter by this code:

```
DbProviderFactory f = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
DbParameter parameter = f.CreateParameter();
```

but you probably have to use some specific platform functionality that SqlParameter implements... as SqlCommand does: SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue() etc.